# Is that series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-z)^{k}\frac{k}{k+\tau\sigma}$ related to a well-known function?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is that series

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-z)^{k}\frac{k}{k+\tau\sigma}$$

with $|z|<1$ related to a well-known function? From "[Is that series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{ak + 1}$ related to a common function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3608606/is-that-series-sum-k-1-infty-fraczkak-1-related-to-a-common-funct)", I know it is similar to a Lerch transcendent but not the same.

Comment: Forget it. I read $(-1)^k$ instead of $(-z)^k$.

Comment: It converges as  $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-z)^{k} = \frac{1}{1+z}$ is the geometric series and as $1\geq \frac{k}{k+\tau\sigma}>0$.

Comment: Did you read my “Forget it”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-z)^{k}\frac{k}{k+\tau\sigma}=-\frac{z }{\sigma  \tau +1}\, _2F_1(2,\sigma  \tau +1;\sigma  \tau +2;-z)$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-z)^{k}\frac{k}{k+\tau\sigma}=(-z)^{-\sigma  \tau } B_{-z}(\sigma  \tau +1,-1)$$

Answer (score 1):

Maple gets
$$ -t\sigma\,{\it LerchPhi} \left( -z,1,t\sigma \right) + \frac{1}{z+1} $$